# Modularising functional tests for a flow consisting of multiple pages in Geb / Spock

Tags: grails, module, spock, geb

I have some functional tests written in Geb / Spock that test several similar but distinct user journeys in my application. Each of the tests caries out a new user registration before proceeding to test their specific scenario.

My question is, what is the best way to modularise a flow like this?

I've looked at [this blog](http://adhockery.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/encapsulating-page-state-and-actions-in.html), which describes how to encapsulate the action of logging into a website - that's a great start, but really I want to be able to encapsulate navigating through a series of pages. I want to create a method like this:

```
public String registerNewUser(String newUsername, String newUserPassword) {
    //step through multiple pages, filling in the various registration forms
}
```

Ideally, I would like to use the GebSpec `to(SomePage)` and `at(SomeOtherPage)` style syntax. Is there some way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply put that method on a base specification? Then you could use the Geb page navigation methods.

```
class BaseSpec extends GebSpec {
    public String registerNewUser(String newUsername, String newUserPassword) {
        to FirstPage
        doSomethingAtFirstPage()
        ....
        to RegistrationPage
        registerUser newUsername, newUserPassword
    }
}
```

Also, the manual section on [Page object builder pattern](http://www.gebish.org/manual/snapshot/pages.html#page_object_builder_pattern) might be of interest for you. Note how `to:` template content options are being used in the examples which means that you don't need to use `to Page` explicitly. Also, since 0.9.0 `to()` method as well as `to:` template option do implicit at checker verification - see [at checking](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/browser.html#at_checking).

Comment: That's not a bad idea, although in the end I actually opted to create a regular class that accesses Browser.getBrowser() statically, and then used at(), to() and waitFor() using the browser instance. I really like the page object builder pattern - I'd not seen this before.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this which I resolved with the base specification idea, which worked quite nicely. If you are interested then take a look at my question (which I updated) [How to setup and teardown functional test data in Geb grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149239/how-to-setup-and-teardown-functional-test-data-in-geb-grails)