# Grails functional test - DB setup/teardown, running as JUnit in Eclipse

Tags: testing, groovy, geb

I am running Geb functional tests in my Grails app through Eclipse "Run As JUnit..."

This normally works great and allows me to keep my test server running with `grails run-app`, and I get fast test execution times.

However, it doesn't allow me to use GORM domain objects in my setup/teardown methods.  Those only work if I run with `grails test-app`, which requires a much longer cycle time.

Is there another way I can access the DB from my functional tests without GORM?  I would be perfectly OK accessing the DB directly through the `groovy.Sql` class, as long as I don't have to duplicate configuration.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149239/how-to-setup-and-teardown-functional-test-data-in-geb-grails - does not address my concern specifically, but the setup/teardown fixtures themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you linked to in your comment actually [does contain a solution in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21453358/1856764) - you should use [Grails Remote Control](http://grails.org/plugin/remote-control) plugin to change the state of your application under test from your functional tests. Some reasons why are outlined in [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28520917/1856764).